# Obtener datos de la URL para mostrar un mensaje en la web

Tags: php, wordpress, web, .htaccess, error404

me gustaría que cuando entrases a una página con la url normal (ejemplo https://www.example.com/) se mostrase el contenido que viene por defecto, pero al añadir un *código* (ejemplo https://www.example.com/?example_code) apareciese un aviso arriba de todo de la página que marcase un aviso. 
Por ejemplo:

> Este es un aviso porque has entrado en una página inexistente, y se te ha redirigido automáticamente hacia la página principal (home).

Esto para el SEO tengo entendido que no tiene repercusión alguna y que no cuenta esa url como una página aparte, sino como una especie de comando. Yo estoy utilizando WordPress y mi idea es esa, la de redirigir a gente que se meta en páginas inexistentes (error 404) a la página principal con una cita arriba que diga un aviso.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir este script a la página de 404:

```
document.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/?str=true';
```

Y después, en la pagina de home, con php puedes ver si existe str y si lo hace añadir un

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['str'])){
    ?>
    <div id="aviso">Este es un aviso porque has entrado en una página inexistente, y se te ha redirigido automáticamente hacia la página principal (home).</div>
    <?php
}
?>
```